# How to copy the Junit report from Jenkins inside email?

Tags: email, jenkins, testing, junit, report

I'm running my testing project by using Jenkins. I can see the Junit report inside Jenkins but now i want to copy the Junit result table inside Jenkins email after every completed run.

I expected the Junit report table can appear inside the email which send from Jenkins automatically.So, whoever receive the email they can know the status of the project.[image: This is Junit report table from Jenkins]

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Jenkins pipeline using JenkinsFile , this can be done as shown below .
generally all unit test cases reports are generated in failsafe-reports in target folder. so try to give the correct pattern to find out the files .

```
def call() {
 def junitPattern = '**/failsafe-reports/*.xml';
 def subject =" write your subject" ;
 String emailTo = "xxx" ;
 def body = " write your mail body"
 def providers = [[$class: 'CulpritsRecipientProvider'], [$class: DevelopersRecipientProvider'], [$class: 'RequesterRecipientProvider']]
 emailext to: emailTo, recipientProviders: providers, compressLog: true, subject: subject, attachmentsPattern: junitPattern , body: body
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not using pipeline. Can you advise another solution?

Comment: How you are building and How you are planning to send an email ? do you use post build actions ?

Comment: yes, I use editable email notification in the post build actions. Now, i am finding way to attach the Junit report table (on Jenkins dashboard) inside my email.

Comment: I tried to attach workspace/*/index.html. it worked, but the index.html is only from the latest run. Previous result is gone.

Comment: Now, I'm running multiple soapui project in one Jenkins job. It only can run one by one project. So, when i run second project, the previous project result will gone. I set 42 projects in one job and i only get the last project result in my local PC. But i still can get the full Junit test report in jenkins dashboard. Is it possible email can copy the dashboard result automatically after run completely? Or, consolidate all the result inside index.html?

Comment: Generally Jenkins will create a work space like below   <JENKINS-HOME>/workspace/<JOB NAME>  and  will do the cleanup and will publish only latest run files only . Jenkins build results are taken from  <JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/<JOB_NAME>builds/<BUILD_NUMBER> . All your results are store here and jenkins internally uses It's own api to publish the latest build results . You will  find out previous results at <JENKINS_HOME>/jobs/<JOB_NAME>builds/<BUILD_NUMBER> .

Comment: Is there any solution to copy dashboard from jenkins inside email? I need complete result inside email

Comment: It's better to publish HTML reports in jenkins UI using HTMLPublihser plugin . Install that plugin and confugure what are all the html's you wan't to publish and yes you can get through mail as well . for attachment pattern , add your own pattern to get all the index.html files              https://wiki.jenkins.io/plugins/servlet/mobile?contentId=42467739#content/view/42467739

Comment: How to attach Junit result inside email?? i know how to attach but i have no idea what path i need to put

Comment: use this one def junitPattern = '**/failsafe-reports/*.xml'; it will search entire workspace for corresponding job and it's latest build number

Comment: I need to put  " **/failsafe-reports/*.xml " in attachment field??